# There is already one outstanding 'SendAsync' call for this WebSocket instance

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

There is already one outstanding 'SendAsync' call for this WebSocket instance. ReceiveAsync and SendAsync can be called simultaneously, but at most one outstanding operation for each of them is allowed at the same time.'

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)

{


    const string Url = @"https://www.instagram.com/stories/afra.saracoglu1fan/3050333333186891216/";

    var driver = new ChromeDriver();
    NetworkManager manager = new NetworkManager(driver);
    manager.NetworkResponseReceived += ResponseHandler;

    Task monitoring = manager.StartMonitoring();
    monitoring.Wait();

    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(Url);


    // Just for demo purposes, in a real world app you might want to await 
    // here in order to not stop the execution
 

    
     void  ResponseHandler(object sender, NetworkResponseReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Http status: {e.ResponseStatusCode}  | Url: {e.ResponseUrl} ");
    }
}
```

Comment: OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools;
using Network = OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V110.Network;
using DevToolsSessionDomains = OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V110.DevToolsSessionDomains;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using GetResponseBodyCommandSettings = OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V110.Fetch.GetResponseBodyCommandSettings;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using OpenQA.Selenium;